# google analytics api v4 unpredictable

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

i am using google analytics api v4 to get some data of an account. it works fine but mostly but unpredictably  i just get this in response, with no data but just row count.

```
 {u'reports': [{u'data': {u'rowCount': 230, u'isDataGolden': True}, u'columnHeader': {u'dimensions': [u'ga:channelGrouping', u'ga:date'], u'metricHeader': {u'metricHeaderEntries': [{u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'ga:users'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'ga:transactions'}, {u'type': u'CURRENCY', u'name': u'ga:revenuePerTransaction'}, {u'type': u'CURRENCY', u'name': u'ga:transactionRevenue'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'ga:itemQuantity'}, {u'type': u'CURRENCY', u'name': u'ga:itemRevenue'}]}}}]}
```

it shows that there are some rows but the rows itself are not returned in respons. why is it so?

Comment: I am having similar issue and haven't figure it out yet. But saw includeEmptyRows on the documentation, maybe it can help. "If set to false, the response does not include rows if all the retrieved metrics are equal to zero. The default is false which will exclude these rows."